# How to change crop zone from code. Using Compose-Cropper library?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I'm using the library https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Cropper.

I'm using a 0 to 100 slider and I want to give the user the ability to customize the crop area with it

I tried changing the overlayRatio with each slider value change. But this option seems too bad, resizing occurs with a delay and intermittently.

Comment: You can't at the moment. But i might add option to disable animation. It's animation playing

Comment: Yes, that would be great. Thank you very much, it would be cool to add the ability to react to the movement of the cutting zone, I saw this was already in the source code, but for some reason there is no callback to the outside

I'm trying to do a functional crop of an image after each movement and paste the cropped image into another image, like a thumbnail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.